# Как изменить шрифт в TextInput , Button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Часть кода:

```
self.But = Button(text='кнопка',
size_hint=(.2, .05),
pos_hint={'center_x': .15, 'center_y': .97})
```

Как изменить шрифт?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы изменить шрифт, нужно передать путь к `ttf` файлу в параметр `font_name`.

```
Button(font_name=`path_to_ttf`)
```